Trouble at wakeup after suspend with XFCE
Basically, when I wake up my system, the mouse works but the rest of the interface is frozen, so I have to restart the XFCE.
So, trying to find the cause, I used the command cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
The result of potentials problems are:
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
AWAC      S4    *enabled   platform:ACPI000E:00

So, I would like help to investigate further and help with the fix.
Thank you so much.
